# In ansible how to display host groups or hosts besides -C?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Is there a way to display host groups or hosts to be applied to without going to the hosts (it takes time even with -C option)? It seems pretty easy to do programatically but I found no information.

In following example, it display ALL host groups in the playbook `genericlinux.yml` but does not show the filter effect of `--limit ansible_test`.

```
$ ansible-playbook genericlinux.yml -D -C --limit ansible_test --tag duosecurity --list-tasks

playbook: genericlinux.yml

  play #1 (generic_linux_east,generic_linux_west,...,ansible_test TAGS: []
    tasks:
      duosecurity : Install package python-pip  TAGS: [duosecurity]
      duosecurity : Install package urllib3     TAGS: [duosecurity]
      ...
      duosecurity : Restart ssh TAGS: [duosecurity]
```

I want to show a list of tasks to be applied on the selected host groups or hosts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ansible` and the `ansible-playbook` commands have the `--list-hosts` option. So to list hosts grouped as `group1`:

For ad-hoc:

```
ansible group1 --list-hosts -i <inventoryfile>
```

For playbook:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --list-hosts -i <inventoryfile>
```

Comment: I just need to add `--list-hosts` to the command in the original post, and it worked, thanks.